# Testing whether an ODE solution is correct yields a constant value for $x$ - what does it mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following linear ODE: 
$$3y' - 6y = 0$$
And I was told to verify that the following expression of $y$ is a solution of the above ODE:
$$y \stackrel{?}{=} \cos x$$
So, $y' = -\sin x$. Therefore:

$$3 (-\sin x) - 6 \cdot (\cos x) \ne 0, \quad\quad \text{for most values of }x$$
So the offered solution **isn't** a solution of the given ODE.

But, after a little manipulation we get: 
$$-3\sin x = 6\cos x \\
-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \tan x = 1\\
\tan x = -2\\
x \simeq -1.1_{rad}$$
What does that value for $x$ mean, exactly?
May we assume that this "truth clause" suggests that the offered solution **IS** a solution for the given ODE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly showed that $\cos x$ is not a solution to the ODE.

The second hald of your calculations show that $x=\tan^{-1}(-2)$ is the solution to $-2\sin x=6\cos x$, but that really has nothing to do with the ODE.